# Android floating window: move it to dismiss

Tags: android, floating

I have a floating window, and now I want to touch and move it to dismiss, whenever I touch on floating window, there is circle shape showed and move floating window toward the circle shape to dismiss itself.

Please see the picture below:

[image: ScreenShot]

How to do it?
Please give an advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to implement this feature from the ground. This feature is similar to Facebook Android client's "chat heads". I've found a library called "Springy Heads" which looks pretty good (also tested it):

[Springy Heads GitHub Page](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads)